# OpenNebula vs. Eucalyptus

Tags: cloud, eucalyptus, opennebula

I am currently learning the basics of cloud computing and in my scripts there are two frameworks mentioned. OpenNebula and Eucalyptus. I've read a few words about each framework but somehow i am not able to fully understand the difference between the two frameworks. So:

Can anybody briefly explain the differences between OpenNebula and Eucalyptus and describe where and why these frameworks are used?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both OpenNebula and Eucalyptus are Cloud Management Platforms. The aim for both of them is to build Public and/or Private Clouds. However, their philosophy is different and thus they address different needs and scenarios, being actually complementary in some ways.

This is a more detailed blog post that was published in OpenNebula's blog analyzing the differences: [Eucalyptus, CloudStack, OpenStack and OpenNebula: A Tale of two Cloud Models](http://blog.opennebula.org/?p=4042)

Full disclosure: I'm a developer of OpenNebula, so my views might be biased, however the blog post is a product of our experience in working in that field and it's about depicting the different scenarios and not about promoting one CMP over another.